# Overriding a method in Obj-c not working

Tags: xcode4, overriding

I'm still on a learning curve with Obj-c.
I'm trying to override the setColumnCount method in the TTThumbsTableViewCell from Three20,
but I don't know why It wont work.
In the method setColumnCount from the super class (TTThumbsTableViewCell) I've added a NSLog(@"Test Super") and the subclass of TTThumbsTableViewCell in setColumnCount method I've add NSLog(@"Test Sub") and the subclass method never prints out "Test Sub".

I'm not sure if I'm overriding correctly in Obj-C, basically I copy the whole method setColumnCount from TTThumbsTableViewCell to the subClass and modify it there, but it still doesn't run the overridden method in the subclass.

Is there something I'm missing?
Im working with XCode 4

Thanks in advance

Brett

South Africa

Comment: Can't tell anything without seeing code…

Comment: Hi Jon Reid, Thanks for the reply, Sorry for the post without Code. Ill reply shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a TTThumbsTableViewCell subClass called GridImage

@interface GridImage : TTThumbsTableViewCell '<'TTPhoto>{

```
//Code...
```

@end

The .m override's the setColumnCount method

'#'import "GridImage.h"

@implementation GridImage

- (void)setColumnCount:(NSInteger)columnCount {
  NSLog(@"Test Sub");
  if (_columnCount != columnCount) {
      for (TTThumbView* thumbView in _thumbViews) {
          [thumbView removeFromSuperview];
      }
      [_thumbViews removeAllObjects];

  ```
  _columnCount = columnCount;

  for (NSInteger i = _thumbViews.count; i < _columnCount; ++i) {
      TTThumbView* thumbView = [[[TTThumbView alloc] init] autorelease];
      [thumbView addTarget:self action:@selector(thumbTouched:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      [self.contentView addSubview:thumbView];
      [_thumbViews addObject:thumbView];
      if (_photo) {
          [self assignPhotoAtIndex:_photo.index+i toView:thumbView];
      }
  }
  ```

  }
  }

Could it be something to do with the '<'TTPhoto> protocol from Three20?